# Office JS Save text as xml file Fails

Tags: download, office-js, savefiledialog

I want to ask **if Office JS is allowed to save local files?**

In old question/answers I found various solutions like
FileSaver.js
Download2.js

I tried both but it did not help.
Both are using the technique of embedding a download link in the HTML document dispatching the event programmatically using JS. **But click event fails with error = Access is denied**

I want to ask if
**Office JS API is allowed to create files to local path?**

if NO was it allowed in older versions?
If YES do I need to make some configuration changes on Windows 10 desktop PC?
If allowed Please help how to achieve that

**I want to create an XML file using JavaScript and save it to local path**
thanks

Comment: No. This was never possible. Office web add-ins (the add-ins that use office-js) are web applications and they cannot directly save to the local file system. You should be able to download however. Which browser is being used when you test? See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: Hmm, Currently I am developing on Windows, but ultimately will need to run in all platforms including Web and IOS. 

Seems like direct download is not the option 
instead the file should be saved to server first (via a web service may be) and then it should open the link in the installed browser. 

as is suggested in last section of the above link you provided to open pdfs. 
What do you think?

Comment: I agree. That is the best strategy.